# How to read the column of text file using Linux shell script and copy the files to another path with in sub directories

Tags: linux, shell

I need a shell script for this:

Ex: I have XMLDataNew.txt file consist with below values

> doument1.doc us        template
>
> doument2.doc us  vimbu standard
>
> doument1.doc us  aldo  template
>
> doument1.doc us  vimbu standard

The above text file read the using shell script and according to columns levels and make the directory path copy the $1 first column values in to respective locations.

I have tried:

```
while read -r line
do 
    id=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    echo $id 
    mkdir -p "/home/mint/Documents/LiveLink/$id" 

    pc=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $3}') 
    echo $pc 
    mkdir -p "/home/mint/Documents/LiveLink/$id/$pc" 

    ct=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $4}') 
    echo $ct 
    mkdir -p "/home/mint/Documents/LiveLink/$id/$pc/$ct" 

done< XmlDataNew.txt
```

Comment: Show what you've tried. We're not **writing** code for you, we're **helping** you.

Comment: while read -r line
do
id=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
echo $id
mkdir -p "/home/mint/Documents/LiveLink/$id"
pc=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $3}')
echo $pc
mkdir -p "/home/mint/Documents/LiveLink/$id/$pc"
ct=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $4}')
echo $ct
mkdir -p "/home/mint/Documents/LiveLink/$id/$pc/$ct"

done< XmlDataNew.txt

Comment: i want copy the selective column files from text file  to another root directories    ..............please sugest me

Answer (score 0):

You could parse lines to columns using `awk` or `cut`, but the correct answer is this:

```
while read name path; do
    path="/home/mint/Documents/LiveLink/${path// //}"
    mkdir -p "$path"
    cp "$name" "$path" # I presume?
done < XMLDataNew.txt
```

The little-known trick is that if you put multiple variable names as arguments to `read`, it will assign consecutive parts of each line into variables, where line is split according to $IFS values. So we can assign first column to variable `name` and rest of line to `path`.

Then I use bashism to substitute space in `path` with forward slash, because that's what you seem to want. If you don't like bashism, you can use `tr` or `sed`.